# AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'new_comment'

Tags: python, attributeerror

**views.py**

```
  def new_comment(request, pk):
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment.post = post
                comment.author = request.user
                comment.save()
                return redirect(comment.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return redirect('/blog/')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('tag/<str:slug>/', views.PostListByTag.as_view()),
    path('category/<str:slug>/', views.PostListByCategory.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/new_comment/', views.new_comment),
    path('delete_comment/<int:pk>/', views.delete_comment),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', views.PostUpdate.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetail.as_view()),
    path('create/', views.PostCreate.as_view()),
    path('', views.PostList.as_view()),
```

I've checked spelling (comment) and indent several times but still don't know what problem is

Comment: Please post code/errors as text in the question body instead of images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

In *urls.py*, I finally found 2 missing points.

Like below, i should add **class name** including new_comment and delete_comment .that is PostListByCategory, prior to them

---

path('/new_comment/',views.PostListByCategory.new_comment),

path('delete_comment//',views.PostListByCategory.delete_comment),